# kivy resize stacklayout based on content

Tags: kivy

I want to use StackLayouts which contain tags as content of an accordion.

Basically the interface group several tags (in StackLayouts) with each tag group as an accordion item.

Like this:

---

### TAG GROUP 1  v

[tag A] [tag B] [tag C]

[tag D] [tag E] [tag F]

---

### TAG GROUP 2  >

---

### TAG GROUP 3  >

---

The (simplified) code:

```
Accordion:
    id: accordion
    orientation: 'vertical'

    AccordionItem:
        title: 'TAG GROUP 1'

        StackLayout:
            Label:
                text: "tag A"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
            Label:
                text: "tag B"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
            Label:
                text: "tag C"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size

    AccordionItem:
        title: 'TAG GROUP 2'

        StackLayout:
            Label:
                text: "tag A"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
            Label:
                text: "tag B"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
            Label:
                text: "tag C"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
```

The problem is I can't get the StackLayout to resize its height based on the number of tags it contains (i.e a group of 3 tags have the same height with group of 10 tags).

I can either set the height to 100% of the parent widget (default) or fix it to a certain height.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

StackLayout have a property named `minimum_height`. That's your savior :)

```
StackLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
```